# Google OAuth "Error 403: org_internal", allow user to select another login

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

This short snip of code is what I'm working on to manage user logins. All I need is to authenticate a user and get his login email address.

I set the app to only accept internal logins, but (while testing) if by mistake I use a generic @gmail.com login I get an error message from which I can't get out.

I'd like the flow to be
Ask for login -> login entered is from wrong domain -> ask again

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
$client->addScope('email');
$client->setApprovalPrompt("select-account");

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $service=new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
  $user = $service->userinfo->get();

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://mysite/book/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}



?>
```

for sake of completness, this is oauth2callback.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://mysite/book/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope('email');

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://mysite/book';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hd param to try to require a particular domain user if that user is present: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#hd-param

Comment: Probably not the cleanest solution, but appears to have done the trick!